# Django - Does not load statics files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am using Django 3.0.8 and like many, I have problems with static files, I have tried many of the recommendations that were previously published but no success.
What I don't understand is that the settings I made, I tried in a Linux environment (Raspbian) and everything works correctly, but when I try on windows 10 with the same settings, same Django version and all, the static files are not loaded, specifically the "css" and "js" files, because images perfectly load so I do not understand why.
Any help I will be very grateful!

This is my settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
```

base.html :

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1"/>  <!--determina si tiene caracter chino,etc-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Bootstrap-Files/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css'%}"/>      
                                 
    <title>{% block title  %}TIMING ADVANCE TA{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block body_section  %}   {% endblock %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'Bootstrap-Files/jquery-3.5.1.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap-Files/js/bootstrap.min.js'%}"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Estructure:

```
|TIGO_TA
|---static
|------Bootstrap-Files
|--------------css
|--------------------bootstrap.min.css
|--------------js
|--------------------bootstrap.min.js
|--------------jquery-3.5.1.js
|------css
|--------------base.css
|------img
|------js
|---templates
|------base.html
|---manage.py
```

Response:

```
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'Tigo_TA.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[18/Jul/2020 12:06:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6745
[18/Jul/2020 12:06:02] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

it seems to load the css but there is no effect on the template created.

Comment: Try removing the subdirectories in Bootstrap-Files and just have the files inside. Or maybe try changing the directory name to just bootstrap as I think the hyphen might be the issue?

Comment: Have you set debug=True in django settings?
The static serve of files can differ between developement server and webserver in production/online. You can read about that here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

If the css is actually loaded but seems not to affect your displayed page, there is maybe a cahced version in your browser. Try to delete the cache (or open in private mode). For chrome and firefox browsers there is also an option to not cache anything while the dev console is open (quite usefull for developement)

Comment: @Harben.-  I changed the directory name to bootstrap as you recommended me and now it exits in the console that got the files...but the problem continues.

Comment: @sarbot Yes it is set debg =True and I delete the cache and open a private mode but not affect the displayed page

Comment: can you see the files content when accessing them directly through the browser?
like is the css shown when requesting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/base.css` after runserver is started?
have you tried to add `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to your url patterns?